# Minimum number of slots

Tags: combinatorics

Question: $13$ people want to conduct one-on-one meetings with each other. There is no limit on number of simultaneous meetings in a given time slot. What is the minimum number of slots required to do this?

Context for the question: This came up as a real logistic problem recently at my office. We did something adhoc. I am looking to see a more structured way to approach this.

Edit: somebody flagged this question as not a suitable mathematics question. So I am just hoping my adding 'context for the question' string above will satisfy their requirement of context to make it mathematical enough.

explanation of 'adhoc': I created an excel sheet and started matching the people against other, taking constraints into account. Did it in a greedy fashion, and was not sure if that was optimal.

Comment: You want ${13\choose 2}=78$ meetings, but there can't be more than $6$ meetings in $1$ time slot, thus you need $13$ slots at least. Did you reach this $13$ with your ad-hoc? Thanks.

Comment: we moved a few people around and broke the rules as suggested in the problem. But it got me interested in problem stated, and if 13 could be achieved.

Comment: Label each person 1 through 13.  Similarly label each time slot 1 through 13.  Then person $x$ meets person $y$ in time slot $n$ if $$x+y\equiv n \pmod{13}$$ (if $2x\equiv n \pmod{13}$ then $x$ has a "bye" during that slot)

Comment: @BrianMoehring nice comment; very slick.

Comment: That was super! thanks @BrianMoehring

Comment: What was the "something" you all "did ad hoc."  How do we know that any question is more structured than your trial, without showing us what you "did ad hoc."

Comment: Please do not assume all "flaggers" you encounter are "gentlemen"; believe it or not, there are women on this site that are highly active. And to refer to any one of them as a gentleman could be seen as rude, even offensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been remarked that $13$ slots are necessary.  It is also true that $13$ slots are sufficient.  Instead of meetings, think of two-person games.  Then we are asking if a round-robin tournament with $13$ players can be scheduled in $13$ rounds.  It is well-known that a round-robin with $2n$ contestants can be scheduled in $2n-1$ rounds.  Here we may add a fictitious $14$th person called "Bye" and schedule the tournament in $13$ rounds.  The person scheduled to meet Bye simply sits out that round.

For those unacquainted with the round-robin scheduling algorithm, this example from "A Course in Combinatorics" by Van Lint and Wilson, will be sufficient explanation.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Given the comment by Brian Moehring and (independently) the answer given
by saulspatz, my response (below) might reasonably be construed to be
**obselete**.  Alternatively, my response might be helpful as a guide for
other (similar) scheduling problems.  Therefore, I leave the response
in place rather than delete it.

..............................

This is a comment rather than an answer.  However, it is so long-winded that it will be easier to understand as an answer.

I agree with Alexey Burdin's comment that 13 slots are necessary.  My (**unproven**) intuition indicates that 13 slots are **also sufficient.**  If each slot features 6 meetings (involving 12 of the 13 people), then the 13 slots would **have to be sufficient.**  So the issue reduces to determining whether the meetings can be scheduled so that each of the 13 slots features 6 meetings.

The only thing that would prevent this would be (for example) if: 
in slot 1, person-1 met with person-2 
in slot 2, person-1 met with person-3 
in slot 3, person-2 met with person-3 
in slot 4, persons 4 through 13 are meeting with each other.

In the above scenario, the last possible meeting in slot 4 can't be used, because in slots 1 through 3, all of the possible ways that 2 of the people from person-1, person-2, and person-3 meet with each other have been **exhausted**.

In order for 13 slots to be sufficient, no meetings can be repeated.  That is, since person-1 met with person-2 in slot-1, the same two people can't also meet in slot-4.

Please advise if you disagree with my analysis; I am really just winging this.  The problem seems to reduce to two separate questions:
(1) Can the 13 slots be efficiently used?
(2) If so, what is the algorithm for their efficient use?

Naturally, the problem generalizes to (2n+1) people.

$\underline{\text{Addendum re : manav's comment}}$

If I were attacking this, I would try two approaches (perhaps simultaneously). 
(1) Consider the cases of (2n + 1) = a smaller number (e.g. n=2 or n=3). 
(2) Attempt to write a computer program that verified that the efficient scheduling is possible when n=2, n=3, ..., n=6.

Then, I would look for **patterns** in the efficient algorithms, and try to prove that such a pattern is always possible.  If this failed, then I would try the opposite approach:  use a computer program to prove that (for example) no efficient scheduling is possible for n=6.  If I was able to prove this by brute force (i.e. computer programming), then I would look for a pattern that I might use to demonstrate for which values of n, efficient scheduling is impossible.

Comment: agree with you on the point that there are two questions here. I would be interested in the algorithm as well.

Comment: @manav your comment triggered an addendum to my *answer*.